# ORDER BY clause error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hey guys I am getting this exception when trying to run the query

> Column `restaurantData.restaurantId` is invalid in the select list
>   because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
>   GROUP BY clause.

Query:

```
SELECT 
    T1.restaurantId AS ID, 
    COUNT(T2.post_id) AS favCount 
FROM   
    restaurantData AS T1 
INNER JOIN 
    favoriteData AS T2 ON T1.restaurantId = T2.post_id 
ORDER BY 
    favCount DESC, ID DESC
```

It says that I have to add all select columns which are not aggregated in `ORDER BY` clause, which I already did for `restaurantID`. But its still giving me error.

Comment: The error message says: `GROUP BY`, not `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing `GROUP BY T1.restaurantId` in the query.

```
SELECT T1.restaurantId   AS ID, 
       COUNT(T2.post_id) AS favCount 
FROM   restaurantData AS T1 
       INNER JOIN favoriteData AS T2 
         ON T1.restaurantId = T2.post_id 
GROUP BY T1.restaurantId
ORDER  BY favCount DESC, 
          ID DESC
```

If you have no `GROUP BY` clause at all then this gives you an aggregate of the whole source table (in which case inclusion of `restaurantId` in the select list is invalid without wrapping that in an aggregate) rather than broken into groups by restaurant as you clearly desire.

Answer (score 4):

You're using an aggregate function (`COUNT`), so you have to use a `GROUP BY` clause as well:

```
SELECT 
    T1.restaurantId AS ID, 
    COUNT(T2.post_id) AS favCount 
FROM   
    restaurantData AS T1 
INNER JOIN 
    favoriteData AS T2 ON T1.restaurantId = T2.post_id 
GROUP BY
    T1.restaurantID
ORDER BY 
    favCount DESC, ID DESC
```

Basically, with your query, you want to count the rows found - and you want the result **grouped by** each `restaurantId` - so that's what the `GROUP BY` clause expresses.